# Django 2.0: How to save 3 ModelForms in 1 view

Tags: django, save, modelform

**How can I save the input from 3 FormModels from one view?**

Hi Stackoverflow, this is my first post here. I've just started learning to code in Python/Django, so my code might be incorrect at all, sorry for that.

After three days of searching and trying a lot of code, my hope is on someone with knowledge :)

What I'm trying to do:

One big form: User fills in personal fields, dossiers fields and the information about a second person. (part not being saved correctly right now)

Views.py one view for 2 ModelForms and reusing one again for c_person.
Models.py 2 models (one dossier and one person data model).
Forms.py 2 ModelForms (one from dossier and one from person, reusing the person form withing the view).

The dossier.html data to give an idea of the form (removed alot of code).

```
                                    <div class="column is-one-fifth">
                                    <label class="label is-small">Firstname</label>
                                    {{ person_form.first_name }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="column is-one-fifth">
                                    <label class="label is-small">Preposition</label>
                                    {{ person_form.preposition }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="column is-one-fifth">
                                    <label class="label is-small">Lastname</label>
                                    {{ person_form.last_name }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="column is-one-fifth">
                                    <label class="label is-small">Address</label>
                                    {{ person_form.address }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="column is-one-fifth">
                                    <label class="label is-small">Firstname</label>
                                    {{ cperson_form.first_name }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="column is-one-fifth">
                                    <label class="label is-small">Lastname</label>
                                    {{ cperson_form.last_name }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="column is-one-fifth">
                                    <label class="label is-small">Number</label>
                                    {{ cperson_form.number }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="column is-one-fifth">
                                    <label class="label is-small">Status</label>
                                    {{ dossier_form.status }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="column is-one-fifth">
                                    <label class="label is-small">Operator</label>
                                    <div class=select>{{ dossier_form.operator }}</div>
                                </div>
```

*models.py*

```
class Person(models.Model):

number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True, blank=True)
initials = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
preposition = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
address_number = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

@property
def full_name(self):
    "Returns the person's full name"
    full_name = (self.last_name + ', ' + self.first_name)

    # Need to check this, django return 'None' if no preposition is used
    if self.preposition:
        full_name = full_name + ' ' + self.preposition

    return full_name

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class Dossier(models.Model):
# Core
status = models.ForeignKey('DossierStatus', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
operator = models.ForeignKey('User', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
d_person = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='d_person', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
c_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='c_person', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)


def __int__(self):
    return self.id

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('dossier_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

forms.py

```
class PersForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ['number', 'first_name', 'preposition', 'last_name', 'initials', 'address', 'address_number', 'email', 'phone_number']

class DossierForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Dossier
    fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def dossier(request):
# if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    dossier_form = DossierForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    dossier_form_valid = dossier_form.is_valid()
    person_form = PersForm(request.POST)
    person_form_valid = person_form.is_valid()
    cperson_form = PersForm(request.POST)
    cperson_form_valid = cperson_form.is_valid()
    # check whether it's valid:
    if dossier_form_valid and person_form_valid and cperson_form_valid:
        print("succes")
        # process the data 
        person_save = person_form.save()
        dossier_save = dossier_form.save(commit=False)
        cperson_save = cperson_form.save(commit=False)

        dossier_save.person_save = person_save
        cperson_save.dossier_save = dossier_save
        cperson_save.save()

        # redirect to a new URL:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/data/index/')
    else:
            print("failure")
            print(dossier_form.errors)
            print(person_form.errors)

# if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
else:
    dossier_form = DossierForm()
    person_form = PersForm()
    cperson_form = PersForm()

return render(request, 'dossier.html',
              {'title': 'Nieuwe aanvraag', 'dossier_form': dossier_form,
               'person_form': person_form, 'cperson_form': cperson_form})
```

Problem here is that only one person form data is being saved to the database.
I've tried lots of differed variations on this code:

```
        person_save = person_form.save()
        dossier_save = dossier_form.save(commit=False)
        cperson_save = cperson_form.save(commit=False)

        dossier_save.person_save = person_save
        cperson_save.dossier_save = dossier_save
        cperson_save.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing the `commit` argument to the `save()` method in a model form, it will save your model in the database. I see the `commit` term here is a little bit misleading, because it sounds like *commit the database transaction*, but it's purely defining if the model's `save()` method will be called or not.

What you want to do is wrap all this code in a single database transaction, using the `django.models.db.transaction`.

First import it in your view:

```
from django.db.models import transaction
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
if dossier_form_valid and person_form_valid and cperson_form_valid:
    print("succes")
    # process the data 

    with transaction.atomic():
        d_person = person_form.save()
        c_person = cperson_form.save()

        dossier = dossier_form.save(commit=False)
        dossier.d_person = d_person
        dossier.c_person = c_person
        dossier.save()
```

The model form `save()` method returns an instance of the Django model it represents. So it renamed it to just `dossier` instead of `dossier_save`, etc.

In the `dossier_form` you can use the `commit=False` because you have more data to associate with the `dossier`, that way you avoid calling the `save()` method multiple times. But for the object to persist in the database, after you add the extra data you need to call the save method like `dossier.save()`.

Everything inside the `transaction.atomic()` block will be executed in a single database transaction, if an error occur, Django will rollback automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Vitor's response is correct, however, the import has changed from:

```
from django.db.models import transaction
```

has changed to:

```
from django.db import transaction
```